# making the subplots of equal width in matplotlib so that labels are seen properly

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot 4 rows of plots in a single figure using GridSpec. Please find the code below:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
gs1=gridspec.GridSpec(4,4)
gs1.update(wspace=0.02,hspace=0.2)
gs2=gridspec.GridSpec(4,4)
gs2.update(wspace=0.03,hspace=0.2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,:])
plt.xlim((0.025,0.065))
plt.xticks([0.025,0.065])
plt.yticks([-1,0,1])
plt.ylabel(r'$p^\prime$(kPa)')
plt.xlabel(r'$t$(s)')


title=['a','b','c','d']

for k in range(4):

if k==0:
    ax2=plt.subplot(gs2[1,k])
    plt.title('%s'%(title[k]))#,size=15)
    ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    plt.yticks([0,25])
    plt.ylabel(r'Y (mm)')


    ax3=plt.subplot(gs2[2,k])
    ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    plt.yticks([0,25])
    plt.ylabel(r'Y (mm)')


    ax4=plt.subplot(gs2[3,k])
    plt.xticks([0,45])
    plt.yticks([0,25])
    plt.ylabel(r'Y (mm)')
    plt.xlabel(r'X (mm)')


elif k>0 and k<(4-1):
    ax2=plt.subplot(gs2[1,k])
    plt.title('%s'%(title[k]))
    ax2=plt.gca()
    ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])



    ax3=plt.subplot(gs2[2,k])
    ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax3.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])



    ax4=plt.subplot(gs2[3,k])
    ax4.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    plt.xticks([0,45])
    plt.xlabel(r'X (mm)')


else:

    ax2=plt.subplot(gs2[1,k])
    plt.title('%s'%(title[k]))#,size=15)
    ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])


    ax3=plt.subplot(gs2[2,k])
    ax3.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])


    ax4=plt.subplot(gs2[3,k])
    plt.xticks([0,45])
    plt.xlabel(r'X (mm)')
    ax4.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])


plt.show()
```

When I run the code, In the resulting figure, the widths of all the figures in all the rows are equal. But, the xlabel of the first row plot goes behind the plots in the second row. When I tried to use plt.tight_layout(),the issue is that the gaps between the rows increased which makes the plot very unpleasant.

I want 
(a) The widths of the plots in all the rows are equal
(b) appropriate spacing between the first row and second row so that the x label and the title of all the figures in the second row are properly seen. 
(c) I do not want too much gap between second, third and fourth rows of figures as obtained using plt.tight_layout().

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: A subplot grid has equal spacings between the rows. Of course you can set that spacing to your liking. You can also use different grids to position your subplots, one with a large spacing, another with a smaller spacing. You may also create unused space in a grid by adding an empty row with enough space for your titles or you position the axes manually, such that they suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I got almost what I wanted by modifying the following the line as gs1.update(top=0.95,wspace=0.02,hspace=0.2)